# Hazelcast map on kubernetes not in sync

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

Writing a spring based application written in kotlin with hazelcast I encounter issue when deploying to kubernetes.

For hazelcast on kubernetes I use [DNS lookup mode](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/deploy/configuring-kubernetes#using-kubernetes-in-dns-lookup-mode) for discovery.
I have the following hazelcast configuration:

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
      kubernetes:
        enabled: true
        service-dns: my-application-hs
```

And the following service.yaml for the kubernetes deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-application

spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: my-application
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-application-hs

spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    component: my-application
  ports:
    - name: hazelcast
      port: 5701
```

A hazelcast map is used like this:

```
@Component
class CacheClientImplHazelcast(){

    private val hz: HazelcastInstance

    init{
        val serializer = SerializerConfig()
            .setTypeClass(MyDto::class.java)
            .setImplementation(MyDtoSerializer())
        val config = Config()
        config.serializationConfig.addSerializerConfig(serializer)
        hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config)
    }

    fun getAllData(): List<MyDto> {
        val map: IMap<String, MyDto> = hz.getMap("my-map")
        return map.values.toList()
    }

    fun putData(key:String, myDto: MyDto) {
        val map: IMap<String, MyDto> = hz.getMap("my-map")
        map.put(key, myDto)
    }

    override fun clear() {
        val map: IMap<String, MyDto> = hz.getMap("my-map")
        map.clear()
    }
}
```

When running 3 instances on kubernetes the logs from hazelcast always show me 4 entries, something like this:

```
Members {size:4, ver:53} [
  Member [10.4.2.32]:5701 - c1e70d6f-a62d-4924-9815-36bb1f98f141
  Member [10.4.3.25]:5702 - be96c292-8847-4f56-ae32-f27f380d7c5b
  Member [10.4.2.32]:5702 - 6ca96bfd-eb74-4149-8630-a2488e76d97d
  Member [10.4.11.41]:5702 - 7e8b0bc9-ad2b-41eb-afbf-b7af9ed497bd this
]
```

(Side question 1: why do I see 4 here instead of 3?)

Now even though it seems the member are connected (at least the logs of the nodes show all the same member uuids) when I write data on one node it is not available on the other nodes. Calls to `getAllData` only show data that has been put into the hazelcast map on this node. When I send requests to the individual nodes (curl on shell) I only see a fraction of the data. When I send a request on the normal url of the pod then with round-robin I get data of the different nodes, which is not synchronized.

If I run the very same application locally with the following hazelcast.yaml:

```
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: false
```

Then it all works correctly and the cache really seems to be "synchronized" across different server instances running locally. For this test I start the application on different ports.

However what is also strange, even if I run 2 instances locally, the logs I see from hazelcast indicate there are 4 members:

```
Members {size:4, ver:4} [
    Member [192.168.68.106]:5701 - 01713c9f-7718-4ed4-b532-aaf62443c425
    Member [192.168.68.106]:5702 - 09921004-88ef-4fe5-9376-b88869fde2bc
    Member [192.168.68.106]:5703 - cea4b13f-d538-48f1-b0f2-6c53678c5823 this
    Member [192.168.68.106]:5704 - 44d84e70-5b68-4c69-a45b-fee39bd75554
]
```

(Side questions 2: Why do I see 4 members even I only started 2 locally?)

The main question now is: Why does this setup not work on kubernetes? Why does each node have a separated map that is not in sync with the other nodes?

Here some log message that could be relevant but I was not able to identify an issue with:

```
2022-04-19T12:29:31.414588357Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.414 INFO 1 --- [cached.thread-7] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnector : [10.4.11.41]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Connecting to /10.4.3.25:5702, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
2022-04-19T12:29:31.414806473Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.414 INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-2] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection : [10.4.11.41]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.4.11.41:5702 and /10.4.3.25:46475
2022-04-19T12:29:31.414905573Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.414 INFO 1 --- [cached.thread-4] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnector : [10.4.11.41]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Connecting to /10.4.2.32:5702, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
2022-04-19T12:29:31.416520854Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.416 INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-0] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection : [10.4.3.25]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.4.3.25:5702 and /10.4.11.41:40455
2022-04-19T12:29:31.416833551Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.416 INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-1] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection : [10.4.2.32]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.4.2.32:54433 and /10.4.11.41:5702
2022-04-19T12:29:31.417377114Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.417 INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-0] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection : [10.4.11.41]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.4.11.41:40455 and /10.4.3.25:5702
2022-04-19T12:29:31.417545174Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.417 INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-2] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection : [10.4.2.32]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.4.2.32:5702 and /10.4.11.41:53547
2022-04-19T12:29:31.418541840Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.418 INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-1] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection : [10.4.11.41]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.4.11.41:53547 and /10.4.2.32:5702
2022-04-19T12:29:31.419763311Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.419 INFO 1 --- [.IO.thread-in-2] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection : [10.4.3.25]:5702 [dev] [5.1.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.4.3.25:46475 and /10.4.11.41:5702
2022-04-19T12:29:31.676218042Z2022-04-19 12:29:31.675 INFO 1 --- [gulis.migration] c.h.i.partition.impl.MigrationManager : [10.4.2.32]:5701 [dev] [5.1.1] Repartitioning cluster data. Migration tasks count: 271
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here but only one problem.

1. why the extra instances

Spring (Boot) will create a Hazelcast instance for you if it finds a Hazelcast config file and no `HazelcastInstance` @Bean. You can fix by excluding the `HazelcastAutoConfiguration.class` or by returning the instance you create in your component class as a @Bean.

2. why the data sync issue on kubernetes

Each pod accidentally has 2 Hazelcast nodes, one on 5701 and one on 5702. But your `ClusterIP` only lists 5701. Some instances in the pod can't be reached from outside. This will go away when you fix the first issue.